# Operators indirectly forbidden (or not?) in defining integer constant expressions (in C)

Tags: c, syntax, c99, language-lawyer

In standard C (C99/C11) we have the so-called **integer constant expressions**, which are constant expressions whose operands are all constant integers.

The following definition applies:

**Standard C99, Section 6.6(par.6):**

> An integer constant expression) shall have integer type and shall
>   only have operands that are integer costants, enumeration constants,
>   character constants, sizeof expressions whose results are integer
>   constants, and floating constants that are the immediate operands of
>   casts.

[Standard C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

This appears after the definition of the more general **constant expression**.
(Since **integer constant expression** are defined after **constant expression**, I assume that the former is a particular case of the last.)

On the other hand, **conditional expressions** are considered **constant expressions**, constrained by the following rule:

**Standard C99, Section 6.6:**

> Constant expressions shall not contain assignment, increment,
>   decrement, function-call, or comma operators, except when they are
>   contained within a subexpression that is not evaluated.

By unrolling the meaning of **conditional expression** we can fall down to **postfix expressions** and/or **unary expressions**.

Now, if we apply these constraints to **integer constant expressions**, we roughly obtain that they consist of conditional expressions restricted in such a way that every operand is integer/enumeration/character constants (or floating constant immediately preceded by a cast), and such that **there are no assignment, increment, decrement, function-call or comma operators**.

- By simplicity, let us suppose that **E** is a such expression, without any `sizeof` operator and without non-evaluated operands.

**MY QUESTION IS:**
Are the following operators indirectly forbidden in **E**:

- `&` (address),
- `*` (indirection),
- `[]` (array-subscript),
- `.` (struct member),
- `->` (pointer to struct members).

In addition, are compound literals also forbidden?

**Aditional note:** I am interested in answering this question for strict conforming programs (C99/C11).

I think that they cannot be in any subexpression of **E**, but I am not sure if this is completely true. My quick reasoning is as follows:

- If **F** is an integer constant subexpression of **E**, then **F** has, by definition, an integer type `T`.
- If the unary operator `&` appears before **F** in **E**, then **&F** ins an operand having type "pointer to T", which is not allowed in **E** (in despite of that **F** is not an object, but only an integer value, so `&` cannot be applied). Thus `&` cannot appear in any **E**.
- Since **F** has not any pointer type, it has no sense the expression `*F`.
- A subscript operator `[]` is used to indicate an element inside an array. This means that we would have in **E** something like `A[N]`. Here, `N` must be an integer constant expression. However we note that `A` is also an operand, but it is an object of type `array`, which is not allowed in **E**. This implies that the array-subscript operator cannot appear in **E**.
- If we have in **E** the operators `.` and `->`, it implies they are used inside **E** as follows: `S.memb   pS->memb`. Thus, we have the operand `S` whose type is `struct` or `union` and `pS` which is a `pointer to struct or pointer to union`. But these kind of "operands" are not allowed in **E**.
- Compound literals are not allowed in **E**, because they are lvalues, which implies they will have an address when the program runs. Since such an address cannot be known by the compiler, the expression involving a compound literal is not considered a constant.

Do you think that my reasonings are right?
Do you know exceptional cases in that some of these operators or expressions can be [part of] an **integer constant expression** (as in the restricted case that I denoted **E**).

Comment: You _are_ kidding, right?  Did you write my calculus book by the way?

Comment: @ryyker: I don't know what you mean. You can point out my mistakes, if you want.

Comment: My comment is a little tongue in cheek, I am hinting that this is one compound and complicated set of questions.  However, someone is bound to take it on.

Comment: @ryyker: It is possible. But I made an explicit question in the paragraph: "My question is: ...". The rest is part of my reasoning about the topic, and it can be discarded. It is additional information or discussion. I can try to rewrite the post, if it is not appropriate.

Comment: Well, you can do this to get the offset of a structure element: `(size_t)&((struct x*)0)->y`. My compiler accepts it as a constant, but I'm not sure how it fits in. Perhaps only because the `&` and `->` cancel out.

Comment: I agree with your reasoning. I suspect some C compilers will be more generous.

Comment: @abligh: I have to add an additional detail: I want to know about  strict conforming to standard C. In this case, you are saying that I am right, is it?

Comment: @ughoavgfhw: I tried with GCC and your example is not working. But I am interested in strict conforming to standards (I added an addtional note to the question). What do you think in this case?

Comment: You did play with the gcc flags -std=c99 -std=c11 -std=gnu99 -std=gnu11 to see if that makes any difference?

Comment: @Johan: I use the gcc flags -std=c99 and -pedantic-errors, because I want to understand strict conforming situation. I tried without the flag -pedantinc-errors, and the program compiles.

Comment: @pablo1977 I do not claim to be a C standards expert but your reading seems correct to me. I upvoted the question so hopefully you will get someone more expert than me looking at it.

Comment: @abligh: Ok, thanks anyway abligh.

Comment: @pablo1977 - _I can try to rewrite the post, if it is not appropriate_    ***No need***...  I think it is appropriate, and, It is written well, albeit more verbose than most.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw, I believe that is a crime outlawed by The Standard, you are supposed to use [offsetof()](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof) (which probably expands to something equally hideous, but guaranteed to work right with your compiler; here (GCC 4.8.2 and clang 3.3 on Linux) it uses a compiler builtin).

Answer (score 3):

An ICE only has to have values (rvalues in the jargon) as primary expressions that constitute it, and no objects (lvalues).

If you build up from there to exclude operators you see that

- none of the operators that need an lvalue as operand can be used (assignment, increment, decrement, unary `&`)
- none of the operators that produce an lvalue can be used either (unary `*`, array member `[]`, member `->`)
- the `.` operators that needs a `struct` as argument, since

  - there are no literals for `struct`
  - Compound literals are a misnomer, they are objects.
  - Function calls are not allowed either.

Some of these operators can appear in places when they are not evaluated (or not supposed not to be), in particular `_Alignof`, the macro `offsetof` and some appearances of `sizeof`.

Comment: Why didn't you insert a second-level list by prefixing with four spaces?

Comment: Not quite so happy. The standard does not define ICE in terms of 'values', because value is `precise meaning of the contents of an object when interpreted as having a specific type`. Also `An implementation may accept other forms of constant expressions`. For example `"abc"[1]` might well be accepted as a character constant.

Comment: @david.pfx, with that narrow explanation of "value", no ICE could represent a value, or (almost) no function call could have a value, since there are not objects involved. That sounds absurd to me.

Comment: I explained nothing. I quoted the standard, I did not write it. My point is simply that your answer is not improved by replacing 'constant' by 'value' given the definition of 'value' provided by the standard. The definitions for 'constant' are much superior.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: I agree with david.pfx about the standard definition of "value". However the standard talks about "value of an expression" as the synonimous for what is commonly known as "rvalue". Besides, the term "computed values" (when talking about expressions) appears in the standard. I think that understanding your term "value" in this sense, your answer would be correct. In 6.4.4 (in C99 std.) is talked about the "value of a constant". It is assumed that a "value" is one the possible elements in a given "type". In particular, every "value" is attached to a "type".

Comment: @pablo1977, exactly that's what I wanted to state in the first phrase of my answer. Value is not much distinguished from rvalue in the standard, and object not much from lvalue. This would probably be a good point for some cleanup, the term value being not much used in the restricted sense that david refers to.